# EasyGrep plugin - is there a way to search only the current buffer

Tags: plugin-easygrep

I came across a vim plugin called [EasyGrep](https://github.com/dkprice/vim-easygrep) and so far it has been great however i wanted to know if it was possible to search only the buffer you are in and if possible specify the path you would like to grep ?

Comment: An issue has been included here. https://github.com/dkprice/vim-easygrep/issues/38

Comment: Very purpose of that plugin is to allow searching g in different directories.

Comment: Easy! Forget EasyGrep. `:vimgrep/pattern/ %`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `%` for defining the path you are searching through:

```
:grep pattern %
```

In a more generic way, after the pattern, you can specify the path you want to search in:

```
:grep pattern **/*.c
```

Depending on the grep program you use, you may need to adjust this but it.

See: `:h grep`

Comment: In easy grep isnt the g in grep supposed to be in capital ?

Comment: Oh, I thought your question was about the build-in grep functionality. My bad.